# Cubic spline fitting

Tags: fitting, splines

If I have the following data:

```
 lengthscale1SB = {{0, 3.2921487465109793`}};
lengthscale2SB = {{100, 2.9436520687559216`}};
lengthscalemix1SB = {{79, 2.495395024671054`}};
lengthscalemix2SB = {{30, 3.333075533653907`}};
lengthscalemix3SB = {{45, 3.1442955345260786`}};
lengthscalemix4SB = {{88, 2.009572697828747`}};
lengthscalemix5SB = {{15, 3.3506633046912224`}};
```

How can I fit it to a cubic spline?

The idea is to try to fit or provide a guide to the eye line to that data perhaps similar to this:

[image]

(* Plot can be generated as:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscale1SB[[1]]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> 16, Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[Automatic, Defer /@ qDSClabel, 
     LegendMarkers -> {Row[{Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12], 
         Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", 16]}, Spacer[2]], 12}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 20}, Spacings -> {.8, 0}], {0.12, 
     0.25}]],
 
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscale2SB[[1]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}],
 
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscalemix1SB[[1]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}],
 
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscalemix2SB[[1]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}],
 
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscalemix3SB[[1]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}],
 
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscalemix4SB[[1]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}],
 
 ListPlot[List /@ {lengthscalemix5SB[[1]]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Gray}],
 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 101}, All}
 
 ]
```

*)

Comment: Did you see the Splines methods: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Splines.html?

Comment: There’s a resource function for that! It is called [`CubicSplineInterpolation`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CubicSplineInterpolation/). From the documentation page, it appears that many cubic spline methods are implemented within it!

Comment: I guess, the simplest way is to use the `BSplineCurve@jointarray` in `Epilog`. Where the `jointarray` is a list with all desired points included.

Comment: @Rom38 could you give me an example of how to do that? I specifically would want to do it with a Spline function/curve.

Comment: Just to second @CATrevillian 's comment:  If you want to connect the points with a smooth curve (and hopefully have some feeling the resulting curve makes sense), then resource function `CubicSplineInterpolation` is what you want.  If the data is put into a single list named `data`, then the following will do what you want:  `f = ResourceFunction["CubicSplineInterpolation"][data]; Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 100}]]`.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of BSpline is simple:

1. Just mix your points into the joint array

   ```
   ar1=SortBy[
   Flatten[{
       lengthscale1SB,
       lengthscale2SB,
       lengthscalemix1SB,
       lengthscalemix2SB, 
       lengthscalemix3SB,
       lengthscalemix4SB,
       lengthscalemix5SB,1],
   First];
   ```
2. Draw it by `BSplineCurve` of desired order

   ```
   ListPlot[ar1,
    Frame -> True,
    PlotStyle -> Blue,
    Epilog -> {Dashed,       
               Red,BSplineCurve[ar1[[1 ;; -2]],SplineDegree->3],
               Black,Line@ar1[[-2 ;; -1]]}]
   ```

[image]

3. You can access the spline points by

   ```
   bsf = BSplineFunction[ar1[[1 ;; -2]], 
                         SplineDegree -> 3]
   bsf[0.5]
   ```

{38.0937, 3.21896}

Here 0.5 is parametric argument for spline that should be in the range [0,1]